# sugarcrm display field in editview based on value in user details

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am trying to display a field in editview alone based on a fieldvale in userdetails.

Ex: For an user `can_add_no` will be in user details, if it is checked than that particular user can add a `quote_extra_no` in `quote` module.

I tried the following. Added dependency for the quote module for the field.

```
$dictionary['Quote']['fields']['quote_extra_no'] = array (
    'audited'                   => true,
    'calculated'                => false,
    'duplicate_merge'           => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'importable'                => 'true',
    'len'                       => '255',
    'massupdate'                => false,
    'merge_filter'              => 'disabled',
    'name'                      => 'quote_extra_no',
    'no_default'                => true,
    'reportable'                => true,
    'required'                  => false,
    'size'                      => '50',
    'source'                    => 'custom_fields',
    'studio'                    => 'visible',
    'type'                      => 'varchar',
    'unified_search'            => false,
    'vname'                     => 'LBL_EXTRA_REF',
    'dependency'                => 'equal(related($assigned_user_link,"can_add_no"),"1")',
);
```

Also added the field in Editview. But its not working. If the current user `can_add_no` is set or checkbox is ticked. He can Edit the  `quote_extra_no` in the editview of the quote.

How can i achive the functionality as the dependency is not helping me to do it.

Comment: Your formula suggests that it is the assigned user of the quote, not the current user. Can you please confirm whether it's the current user, or the assigned user that needs to have that property?

Comment: Assigned user @Reisclef

Comment: Okay, so is it only if the current user is the assigned user, and said user has can_add_no ticked? If so, it's possible through a custom view. If you can't solve it from the existing answer, I'll see if I can help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two may to do that  for both way you should have relation between both module.

1. By Using Dependency :

   equal(related($related_field_name,"can_add_no"),"1")'
2. IN record.js write a  method in that method call a api  for `canadd_no` and according to that show hide the field.

API call Example :

```
  app.api.call('read', app.api.buildURL(this.model.get('_module'), 'read', {id: this.model.get('id')}), null,
                {
                    success: function(data) {
                          your costume code to hide
                        }
                    },
                });
```

[More Info related to API](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/API/Web_Services/Examples/v10/)

Comment: any sample for API method? pls

Comment: I add Sample of API method.